# unirest - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException

Tags: java, http, runtime, unirest

I am trying to use Unirest-Mashape to build java applications.

This is my code:`import com.mashape.unirest.http.*;`

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.json.*;
public class request {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards").header("X-Mashape-Key", "<required>").asJson();
}
}
```

When I compile my code, It shows no error. But when I run it, it shows the following runtime error :  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/reactor/IOReactorException
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:151)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at request.main(request.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more`

[I've got included this clases to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWgM9.png)

But still I am getting the error. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You didn't actually include your code (it just says `enter code here`). Make sure you check the preview before posting to avoid accidents like this.

Comment: i've edited it yet

Answer (score 0):

You need httpcore-nio also. The Unirest Java section is pretty bad, and is missing most of the dependencies.